# Dúvida na utilização do DateFormat em servidor vinculado (linked)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte situação.

Executo esse `script`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, 12) + '/' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 31) + '/' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 1900) + ' ' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0) 
                         + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0))
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 242, Nível 16, Estado 3, Linha 2 A conversão de um tipo de
>   dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora
>   do intervalo.

Se add o comando  `Set Dateformat mdy` o script funciona corretamente:

> 31/12/1900 00:00:00

**Dúvida:**

Estou fazendo um `update` em uma tabela de um servidor vinculado, nela possui uma `trigger` onde existe o  `script` citado acima. Então tento colocar o `dateformat` antes do `update`, mas retorna o erro citado. Percebo que isso acontece pois estou logado em uma sessão e o servidor vinculado está em outra e assim retorna o erro.

Como posso tratar isso ?  levando em conta que não posso alterar a `trigger` do server vinculado (*linked*)

**Lembrando que os dois usuários em cada server estão com a linguagem português brasil .

Comment: Não seria mais fácil você utilizar o convert(datetime, '20200101 03:04:21',103)? Assim não precisa usar o DateFormat

Comment: @MarcosACR o problema é que não posso alterar esse script, pois é um ERP da empresa que estou buscando via linked. Estranho é que se eu executar lá dentro do servidor que faço o linked funciona, mas executando via linked acusa o erro de data.

Answer (score 1):

Você está colocando a data no formato mês/dia/ano. Sabemos disto porque a primeira componente é 12 (obviamente dezembro), a segunda componente é 31 (o último dia de dezembro), e a terceira é o ano (1900). Acontece que não é legal converter datas neste formato, pois vai depender da configuração do servidor. Um servidor no formato americano vai entender, outro servidor configurado para o formato brasileiro não vai entender.

A melhor forma é usar sempre a forma chamada "canônica", isto é, ano, mês e dia, que será sempre entendida, independente de configuração:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, 1900) + '/' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 12) + '/' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 31) + ' ' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0) 
                         + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0))
```

Uma outra possibilidade é colocar como terceiro parâmetro da função CONVERT, o formato de conversão desejado. Para entender como mês/dia/ano, o código seria: 101.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, 12) + '/' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 31) + '/' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 1900) + ' ' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0) 
                         + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 0),
               101)
```

Então usar uma conversão de um formato não convencional, sem explicitar o formato desejado, não é uma boa prática, porque fica dependendo da configuração do servidor. O script deveria ser robusto o suficiente para rodar sempre da mesma forma. Então ou coloque sua data na forma canônica, ou explicite o formato desejado. Ambas as soluções devem funcionar.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15